# PNG TO TFRecord: error : has type numpy.ndarray, but expected one of: bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, png, tfrecord

I'm doing a .png file to tfrecord.

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Wrapper for inserting bytes features into Example proto."""
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

convert to example file:

```
def _convert_to_example(filename, image_buffer, label, text, height, width):
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
    'image/width': _int64_feature(width),
    ........
    'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(image_buffer)})) #Error
    return example
```

decode_png file, not sure this part

```
def decode_png(image_data):

    img_str = image_data.tostring()
    reconstructed_img_1d = np.fromstring(img_str, dtype=np.uint8)
    reconstructed_img = reconstructed_img_1d.reshape(image_data.shape)

    return reconstructed_img
```

process_image file:

```
def _process_image(filename):

    # Read the image file.
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        image_data = io.imread(f)

    # Decode the RGB PNG.
    image = decode_png(image_data)

    # Check that image converted to RGB
    assert len(image.shape) == 3
    height = image.shape[0]
    width = image.shape[1]
    assert image.shape[2] == 3

    return image_data, height, width
```

Main, process image files batch:

```
for i in files_in_shard:
        filename = filenames[i]
        label = labels[i]
        text = texts[i]

        image_buffer, height, width = _process_image(filename)

        example = _convert_to_example(filename, image_buffer, label,
                                      text, height, width)
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
        shard_counter += 1
        counter += 1
```

But, there is a error that `TypeError: array([[[223, 198, 219],
        [215, 185, 209],
        [207, 174, 201],
        ...,
        [230 has type numpy.ndarray, but expected one of: bytes`

How should I deal with this? Any help would be great.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it... logic pro

```
def decode_png(image_data):

img_str = image_data.tostring()
reconstructed_img_1d = np.fromstring(img_str, dtype=np.uint8)
reconstructed_img = reconstructed_img_1d.reshape(image_data.shape)

return img_str


def _process_image(filename):
    # Read the image file.
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        image_data = io.imread(f)

    # Decode the RGB PNG.
    img_str = image_data.tostring()

    height = image_data.shape[0]
    width = image_data.shape[1]

    return img_str, height, width
```

Comment: You also have the option:
`
img_str = image_data.tobytes();
reconstructed_img_1d = np.frombuffer(img_str, dtype=np.uint8)
`

This might be faster, but I didn't actually test it.